# How can i remove noise from sound coming from my computer mic jack ?

Tags: audio-recording, audio, sound, audio-interfaces, engineering

Normaly The signal comming from the  computer audio jack should not have any noise.
But when i connect the signal to my oscilloscope i see a lot of noise in the signal.
How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computers' built-in sound devices are notoriously cheap & cheerful... & noisy.

The only real 'fix' would be to invest in a reputable outboard device, connected over USB.